# Attach Twitter stream/ public dataset as input for YCSB's workloads

Tags: twitter, stream, dataset, benchmarking, ycsb

YCSB's workloads use auto generated data. Is there a way to attach public dataset of Twitter or other services as input for the workloads? I need to use causality aspect of those dataset. (E.g. {id, tweet, parent-id..}

Answer (score 0):

You can't in vanilla YCSB, but you could use the [KV-replay](https://github.com/ebozag/KV-replay) fork instead. The workload (trace) needs to be modified to their input format, but that should be easy to do in Python or bash.